# Fail to execute linux command in RHEL using java

Tags: java, linux, bash

I had developed a java program that able to run the Linux command in Ubuntu, but when I try the same program in rhel, my code cant working,my code not able to execute the Linux command, but if I directly executed the command through the terminal,it's able to show the output
This is the my sample program 
 Do the Ubuntu having any different with RHEL ?I had checked my bash file for the rhel in under `/usr/bin` folder

```
String temp1 = "'/" + t1 + "/,/" + t2 + "/p'";
String command2 = "sed -n " + temp1 + "\t" + confstr2;
System.out.println( "The command2 is : " + command2 );
ProcessBuilder pb1 =
    new ProcessBuilder(
        "/usr/bin/bash",
        "-c",
        command2
    ).directory( new File( confstr3 ) );
Process p2 = pb1.start();
BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( p2.getInputStream() ) );
String line2;
File file1 = new File(confstr4);

if(file1.createNewFile()) {
    System.out.println("File is created!");
}
else {
    System.out.println("File already exists.");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using /bin/bash? It is the standard location for `bash`.

Comment: Can you show us the exception stacktrace you get ?

Comment: You should either read error output, or use `redirectErrorStream(true)` on the `ProcessBuilder`. Without this you're ignoring the only error message that could help you.